# How to make bootstrap card clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

In order to use on my website, I am trying to make bootstrap cards clickable. 
But when I wrap boxes with "ahref" link, there are a lot of styling problems. 
The boxes becomes smaller. I tried a lot of alternatives however I couldn't find why I am having problem with it.

You can also find https://codepen.io/snarex/pen/ebQdgj which I have made some test.

```css
section {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    background-color: #f1f4fa;
}
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    background: white;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 30px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.wrap:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,#6394ff 0%,#0a193b 100%);
    color: white;
}

.ico-wrap {
    margin: auto;
}

.mbr-iconfont {
    font-size: 4.5rem !important;
    color: #313131;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
.vcenter {
    margin: auto;
}

.mbr-section-title3 {
    text-align: left;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
.display-5 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.mbr-bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}

 p {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.display-6 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1re
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<section>
<div class="container">

 
  <div class="row mbr-justify-content-center">

            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-volume-up fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Stay <span>Successful</span></h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-calendar fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Create
                            <span>An Effective Team</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-globe fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Launch
                            <span>A Unique Project</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mbr-col-md-10">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="ico-wrap">
                        <span class="mbr-iconfont fa-trophy fa"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-wrap vcenter">
                        <h2 class="mbr-fonts-style mbr-bold mbr-section-title3 display-5">Achieve <span>Your Targets</span></h2>
                        <p class="mbr-fonts-style text1 mbr-text display-6">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            

            
        </div>

</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try making your `a` tags `position: absolute;` like so...

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{
  position: relative;
}
.wrap a{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

The `a` tag now sits on top of your card and should grow and shrink with the card as needed. You can also add `border-radius` to the `a` tag to match the corners of your card.

I also updated your [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGOgMq) so you can see the changes in the inspector to get a better idea of whats going on.